# Draw polyline whenever Animating the vehicle

Tags: google-maps, direction

Application running successfully with Animation features.
Below code animating a vehicle Icon through a polyline.

In below code, How to draw a poly line when vehicle animate through the route?Like this Jsfiddle
[Red Line at the time of animating](https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/dk1zp2n8/)

I tried but always line is showing before start animation.
Need existing polylines and new line at vehicle movement.

```
    var step = 50; // 5; // metres
        var tick = 100; // milliseconds
        var eol;
        var k = 0;
        var stepnum = 0;
        var speed = "";
        var lastVertex = 1;

        //=============== animation functions ======================
        function updatePoly(d) {
            // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
            if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
                poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex - 1)]);
                // map.addOverlay(poly2)
            }
            if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex + 2) {
                if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
                    poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength() - 1);
                }
                poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(), polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
            } else {
                poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(), endLocation.latlng);
            }        

      
        }

        function animate(d) {
            if (d > eol) {
                map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
                Animationmarker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
                return;
            }
            var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
            map.panTo(p);
            var lastPosn = Animationmarker.getPosition();
            Animationmarker.setPosition(p);
            var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(lastPosn, p);
            icon.rotation = heading;
            Animationmarker.setIcon(icon);
            updatePoly(d);
            tick = document.getElementById('<%= DrpAnimateSpeed.ClientID%>').value;
           
           // alert(tick);
            timerHandle = setTimeout("animate(" + (d + step) + ")", tick);              
            currentDistance = d + step;                    



        }

    function startAnimation() {
        if (timerHandle) {
            clearTimeout(timerHandle);
        }
        if (Animationmarker) {
            Animationmarker.setMap(null);
        }
  
            eol = polyline.Distance();
            map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
            Animationmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: polyline.getPath().getAt(0),
                map: map,
                icon: icon
            });

            poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)],
                strokeColor: "orange",
                strokeWeight: 20
            });


             //map.addOverlay(poly2);
            setTimeout("animate(50)", 2000); // Allow time for the initial map display
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any polyline in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/dk1zp2n8/)  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site like jsfiddle.

Comment: @geocodezip Click on the play button on the top of map...then vehicle starts moving with red polyline...Just near to Map satelite option...Actually Play button is very small  in this example....This feature I meed to update in my coding

Comment: Missed that (it is fairly small, I probably didn't see the "play" button).  Still don't see a [mcve] that demonstrates your existing code.

Comment: @geocodezip   I used same coding in this http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ouhLc6v2/  
 link.. How to show the red line whenever vehicle moves  through the blue line? 
  https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/dk1zp2n8/.   I tried many ways ..and failed

Answer (score 0):

[Red -Blue line difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4GVZ.png)  Added this below code in animate() function  and drawing another polyline when animated icon is moving.
Here the problem I am facing is, Some places red line is showing like image..In the image blue line is based on direction service route. and red is the one drawing based on the below code.How to solve this?

```
            ///Ad[enter image description here][1]ded             
            HighlightPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [],
                strokeColor: 'red',
                strokeWeight: 4
            });
            var codeStr = [];
            const path = [lastPosn, p];
            HighlightPoly.setPath(path);
            HighlightPoly.setMap(map);
            //////////////////////
```